# Always show the calendar in WPF's date picker

Tags: .net, wpf, datepicker

I put a DatePicker control on my WPF application, but I don't want the calendar to only be visible when the icon is click, I want the calendar to always be visible.

I'd like to be able to do this purely in the XAML, but if I have to do it within the C# code, hey whatever works.

I'm using C# .NET 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTimePicker from http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker

There is property IsOpen, just set it to true.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  I've started to notice the default controls are very feature lacking, going with a 3rd party control pack was inevitable.

Comment: these control packs are called Toolkits and also they usually contain more then just controls